# About the set of all homomorphisms from $G$ to $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove or disprove:

a)
If $H$ be an abelian group then  $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},H) \cong H$. (note that $\operatorname{Hom}(G,H)$ is set of all homomorphisms from $G$ to $H$).

b) if $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(m,n)=d$ then $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m) \cong \mathbb{Z}_d$

I think that for "a" if $H=\mathbb{Z}$ then $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}) =\operatorname{Aut} (\mathbb{Z})$ and $|\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})| =2$ and "a" is false. for "b" if $m=n$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_n)= \mathbb{Z}_n\neq \operatorname{Aut} (\mathbb{Z}_n) = U(n)$ and $| \operatorname{Aut} (\mathbb{Z}_n)| = \phi(n)$

Comment: $End(\mathbb{Z})$ has many more than only $2$ elements.

Observe that every morphism $f \colon \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow H$ is completely determined by its action on a generator of $\mathbb{Z}$, for example $f(1) = h$ for $h \in H$ gives infinitely many morphisms.

Try thinking about this to see how one can relate $Hom(\mathbb{Z},H)$ with $H$.

Comment: $Hom(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}) \cong End(\mathbb{Z})$, not $Aut(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @Klaramun.$Aut (\Bbb{Z})$ has tow elements because f(1)= 1 or -1

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about $Hom(\mathbb{Z},H)$ as @lisyarus said. I just dont know how to edit the comment.

Comment: @Klaramun. Please click on" edit". In right side of your text.

Comment: Why should Hom be the same as Aut?

Comment: @egreg.because Hom(G,H)  is set of all homomorphisms from G to H ,and Aut(G) is set of all homomorphisms from G to itself.is it not true? Why?

Comment: @amirbahadory Aut(G) consists of invertible homomorphisms, not all homomorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), define a map $\Phi:\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},H)\to H$ by $\Phi(\phi)=\phi(1)$. Then, $\Phi$ is a group homomorphism since $\Phi(\phi+\psi)=(\phi+\psi)(1)=\phi(1)\psi(1)=\Phi(\phi)\Phi(\psi)$.

To see that $\Phi$ is injective, note that for any $\phi\in\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},H)$, $\phi(n)=\phi(1)^n$ (I'm writing the product in $H$ multiplicatively), so if $\Phi(\phi)=\phi(1)=\psi(1)=\Phi(\psi)$, then $\phi(n)=\phi(1)^n=\psi(1)^n=\psi(n)$. That is $\phi=\psi$. Finally, for $h\in H$, let $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to H$ be the map defined by $\phi(n)=h^n$. Then $\phi(1)=h=\Phi(\phi)$. Hence $\Phi$ is surjective and an isomorphism.

Note that (b) is also true (and can be proved in a way similar to (a)). You just need to determine when a homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_n\to\mathbb{Z}_m$ given by $\phi([1]_n)=[x]_m$ is well defined.